# How to communicate between a JSP filter and a JAVA program

Tags: string, jsp, send

Is there any way to send a string to a JAVA program from a JSP filter?

I tried sockets; didn't work.

I tried external files; didn't work.

So, I'm kind of at a Witt's end here on the subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by *sending a String to a Java program*? Is the program on a separate process?

If that's the case and you need synchronous communication, you can definitely use TCP sockets or just UDP. Place the server socket on your *Java program*.

If you can *run* your Java Program as a separate thread on the Tomcat server, then it will be a better and faster solution. Just add the *JAR* file where your *Java program* is and launch it on a separate thread with a REQUEST queue to interact with the filter.